# how to create a pivot table in Excel using Open XML SDK(XLSX)

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, openxml-sdk, pivot-table

From my .net web application, I need to generate a pivot table in excel file using Open XML SDK. I tried to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, but it was giving me error while I run it on IIS. Please help me to do this using Open XML SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is some info from MS on Pivot with OpenXML:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278324.aspx

Comment: can you please provide any sample code to create pivot table in web application using Open XML SDK